# Kivy: how to change widget size using numericproperty?

Tags: python, widget, size, kivy

Trying to make a brick widget change size each time it respawns.

The py file has

```
class Game(FloatLayout):
    player = ObjectProperty(None)
    playbutton = ObjectProperty(None)
    ratebutton = ObjectProperty(None)
    brickg = ObjectProperty(None)
    ballsin = NumericProperty(0)
    bricklist = ListProperty([])
    score = NumericProperty(0)
    switch = NumericProperty(0)
    level = NumericProperty(0)

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Game, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1./60)

    def spawn_brick(self, *args):
        b2 = BrickGreen(x=randint(50, self.width - 50), \
        y=randint(self.height - self.height / 4, self.height - (self.height/13)))
        self.bricklist.append(b2)
        self.add_widget(b2)

    def check_brick_spawn(self, *args):

        if len(self.bricklist) == 0:
            if self.level == 0:
                BrickGreen.brickwidth = 100
                self.spawn_brick()
            elif self.level == 1:
                BrickGreen.brickwidth = 75
                self.spawn_brick()
            else:
                BrickGreen.brickwidth = 50
                self.spawn_brick()

class BrickGreen(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BrickGreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        brickwidth = NumericProperty(0)
```

and the kv file has

```
<BrickGreen>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: self.brickwidth, 25
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 1, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

Essentially, level 0 should have bricks with length of 100, once it breaks it goes to level 1 and should spawn bricks with lenght of 75, but it's staying at 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> BrickGreen.brickwidth = 100

This replaces the NumericProperty at class level with the number 100. You need to set the value of brickwidth for *instances* of your objects, not the classes themselves. In this case, you could (for instance) pass the width you want to your `spawn_brick` method, and use it when instantiating the BrickGreen.

You also need to declare the NumericProperty at class level, not inside `__init__`.

I suggest reading the kivy documentation on properties and going through the examples to see how these should be used.

Comment: Great, thank you inclement. That works, but I'm having an issue now. The ball will only collide with a portion of the widget. So I set the widget length to 300 when I add it through the spawn_brick function, but the ball will only collide with about 100 width of the widget.